# How do regex engines account for irregularity?

Tags: regex, algorithm, finite-automata

My C is a bit shaky, but I've looked at python's source code and it looks like most of python's `re` module is implemented by state machines. This comes as no surprise since regular expressions can be reduced to deterministic finite state machines.

I imagine other regex implementations are similar. But few, if any, modern regex implementations are regular according to the textbook definition. Then how do they account for irregularity, like backreferences?

```
(.*)\1   // this is not regular
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use an amended (beyond finite state) automaton class to account for this, and more complicated matching algorithms than the [vanilla Thomson algorithm](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html). You're very lucking if you find a formal characterization of the automaton class that any particular "RE" engine supports.

From what I can make up from the Python `re` source code, it stores the group in a buffer (it has to anyway, since it must return this as part of the match object) and does a straightforward string match in the matching algorithm, consuming as many characters as there are in the group match buffer.

[Optional rant: unfortunately, RE engines in practice are collections of hacks on top of NFAs that destroy their mathematical properties. Many implementers ignore the elegant algebra of [regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) and their powerful extension to regular relations, which can be efficiently captured by [FSTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer).]